# Add Visibility Filter to product collection in category page in M2

Tags: magento2

I have to add a visibility filter on category page on the selection of particular Filter i.e Size from Layered navigation.

I have to show the products whose visibility is set as Catalog only.

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this below code :

```
protected $_productCollectionFactory;

public function __construct(
    .....
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
    .....
) {
    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function getProductCollection($category_id_array)
{
    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->addCategoriesFilter(['in' => $category_id_array]);
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG);
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
    $collection->setPageSize(9); // fetching only 9 products
    return $collection;
}
```

We can add more two filters like

```
\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_SEARCH
\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH
```

Comment: How I have to override my default collection in category page? I was using a plugin. Because it will add the visibility on a particular case if I will size in layered navigation.

Comment: I have to add a visibility filter on size selection.

Comment: very helpful Thanks @Rohan